# find alphabets count per date in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've a list of dates and alphabets. I've to find count of alphabets occurring within a week. I'm trying to group by them by alphabets and re-sample it by '1w'. But i get some weird data frame which contains MultiIndex. How can i do all this and get the DataFrame with just three rows containing score, new re-sample date and count?

PS: What i'm looking for is a week and count for occurrence of every alphabet in that week.
something like that

```
datetime                        alphabet   count
2016-12-27 22:57:45.407246         a      1
2016-12-30 22:57:45.407246         a      2
2017-01-02 22:57:45.407246         a      0
2016-12-27 22:57:45.407246         b      0
2016-12-30 22:57:45.407246         b      1
2017-01-02 22:57:45.407246         b      4
2016-12-27 22:57:45.407246         c      7
2016-12-30 22:57:45.407246         c      0
2017-01-02 22:57:45.407246         c      0
```

Here is the code

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import datetime



def randchar(a, b):
    return chr(random.randint(ord(a), ord(b)))

# Create a datetime variable for today
base = datetime.datetime.today()
# Create a list variable that creates 365 days of rows of datetime values
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 365)]

score_list =[randchar('a', 'h') for i in range(365)]

df = pd.DataFrame()

# Create a column from the datetime variable
df['datetime'] = date_list
# Convert that column into a datetime datatype
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
# Set the datetime column as the index
df.index = df['datetime']
# Create a column from the numeric score variable
df['score'] = score_list

df_s = tt = df.groupby('score').resample('1w').count()
```

Comment: Are you looking for `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1w')).score.transform('count')
`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ What i'm looking for is a week and count for occurrence of every alphabet in that week. check question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a `groupby` + `count` with 2 predicates -

1. `pd.Grouper` with a frequency of a week
2. `score` column

Finally, `unstack` the result.

```
df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1w'), 'score']).count().unstack(fill_value=0)
df.head() 

           datetime                     
score             a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
datetime                                
2016-12-25        0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1
2017-01-01        1  0  0  1  3  0  2  0
2017-01-08        0  3  1  1  1  0  0  1
2017-01-15        1  2  0  2  0  0  1  1
2017-01-22        0  1  2  1  1  2  0  0
```